# Convert struct tm to time_t

Tags: c++, time

I have the following code:

```c
struct tm time;

strptime("27052010", "%d%m%Y", &time);

cout << "sec: " << time.tm_sec << "\n";
cout << "min: " << time.tm_min << "\n";
cout << "hour: " << time.tm_hour << "\n";
cout << "day: " << time.tm_mday << "\n";
cout << "month: " << (time.tm_mon + 1) << "\n";
cout << "year: " << time.tm_year << "\n";

time_t t = mktime(&time);

cout << "sec: " << time.tm_sec << "\n";
cout << "min: " << time.tm_min << "\n";
cout << "hour: " << time.tm_hour << "\n";
cout << "day: " << time.tm_mday << "\n";
cout << "month: " << (time.tm_mon + 1) << "\n";
cout << "year: " << time.tm_year << "\n";

cout << "time: " << t << "\n";
```

The output is:

```c
sec: 1474116832
min: 32767
hour: 4238231
day: 27
month: 5
year: 110

sec: 52
min: 0
hour: 6
day: 2
month: 9
year: 640
time: 18008625652 (Fri, 02 Sep 2540 04:00:52 GMT)
```

My question is why does `mktime()` change the values of `time` and why is the converted `time_t` not equal to my input date. I would expect that the output is the date expressed in seconds since 1970 (27.05.2010 = 1330905600).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What were the values of `time.tm_hour`, `time.tm_min` and `time.tm_sec` before the call to `mktime`?

Comment: @Wintermute I added the informations.

Comment: Err... you took an uninitialized struct, initialized three out of its many fields, then "converted" it (three meaningful values plus a lot of garbage), then read the fields back and wonder why you're getting mostly garbage? ;-) GIGO, really.

Comment: The problem are the high values of hour, min and sec am I right? mktime() will convert these out of ranges values and it the according the values to the next higher unit? (25hours -> 1 hour but +1 day).

Comment: Clear `time` before calling `strptime()`, else the random values in other fields are being adjusted by `mktime()` to their normal range and affecting y,m,d.

Comment: `mktime()` looks at _all_ fields except `tm_yday, tm_wday`.  So the state of the other 7 (or more) need to be initialized.

Comment: @aQuip Exactly so. Just like 40 October is changed into 9 November (that's the example from the man page).

Answer (score 14):

`mktime` normalizes all its arguments before converting to a `time_t`. You have huge values for hour, minute and second, so those are all converted into appropriate numbers of days, pushing the value far into the future.

You need to zero out the other important attributes (including hour/minute/second) of the `tm` before calling `mktime`. As noted in a comment just initialize it to zero: `tm time = {0};` (tagged C++ so the leading `struct` isn't needed). Further note that you may wish to set `tm_isdst` to -1 so that it attempts to determine the daylight saving value rather than assuming not DST (if initialized to zero).

Comment: Is there a smarter way than setting all values manually two zero? Sorry I'm not really familiar with C.

Comment: "zero out the hour/minute/second" is insufficient.  All fields, expect `tm_yday, tm_wday`, need to be initialize including `tm_isdst` and potential others and the total set of fields is not defined, hence "simple assignment to those attributes." may not initialized all fields unless the code knows what they all are.

Comment: @aQuip `struct tm time = {0};`